# Setting up .NET Core development environments with IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis

I'm new to .NET core.  We're currently implementing an Umbraco9 site which is running on .NET core 5 (MVC). Normally when setting up a development environment on a regular .NET site, I would create the project, point IIS to that same folder, and create a host entry for something like "local.mysite.com"  I would then just be able to load up that URL in my browser and the site would serve, simply building when changes to back-end code were needed.

With .NET core, there are obviously some significant differences.  For starters, there is a new wwwroot folder inside the project.  So, in this case, I've tried pointing my IIS site to that wwwroot folder.  This then has the impact of requiring a visual studio publish to that folder for any change front-end or back-end.  Furthermore, it seems as though .NET core compiles the cshtml files into a Views.dll file, but when I publish the site, the site throws a 500 unless I manually copy the cshtml files to the wwwroot folder (which also has its own wwwroot after publish).

I've done loads of research on what the generally accepted best practices are with developing and hosting .NET core, but haven't come to a conclusion on this.  Further complicating this is that I've seen some information saying that you can use Kestrel in conjunction with IIS. So now it's a matter of Kestrel vs. IISEx vs IIS.  I'd prefer IIS as I'd like it to match production.

I've tried setting my IIS path to the path of the VS project, but I get "web server is not configured to list the contents of this directory."  I enabled directory browsing, but this of course just lists the files in the directory.  I've installed the hosting bundle as well.

The question: Is there a set of generally accepted practices on how to setup local development environments for .NET core projects?  I'm really looking for some guidance on .NET core from a non .NET core developer's perspective. I'm trying to make this question as focused as possible, but I feel like there's a gap in my understanding of "old .NET" vs. .NET core and I'm hoping to get some guidance to help fill in that gap.

Comment: Point IIS to **the parent of** the `wwwroot` folder, and make sure you have the correct hosting bundle installed.

Comment: Updated original post.  I tried your suggestion, but I get an IIS error about it not being able to list the contents of the directory. I did enable this, but it just lists the contents as expected.

Comment: Have you installed [the .NET 5 Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.14-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)?

Comment: The hosting bundle has been installed, updating original post as well.

Comment: It has been available since 2017, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/ so I wonder why your investigation didn't lead you there.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but I had to setup a visual studio publish profile and publish to a separate folder which I then pointed IIS to. I could not get it to work "in place."

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this figured out, so only solution I can come up with is to  point IIS at a separate publish folder and publish to that folder when I need to make changes.